# AngularJS: Data binding producing empty HTML tags (Django Conflict)

Tags: javascript, html, django, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am attempting to fetch some data from my API, and generate a navigation bar based on the data returned.

It appears as though Angular is successfully adding the new elements to the DOM, but they are empty. I've verified that the data returned from the API is correct, and what I am expecting. To make things even weirder, the code works on my local machine but fails during deployment (on a remote server).

Any idea how/why Angular would be producing empty HTML tags, instead of filling them with the correct data?

**EDIT**: I figured out the issue. Turns out it was caused by Django/Angular conflict.

Here is the relevant code:

**sidebarCtrl.js**

```
(function() {
    var ppApp = angular.module('ppApp');

    ppApp.controller('sidebarCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.categories = {
            'Foo': [],
            'Bar': [],
            'Spam': [],
            'Eggs': [],
        };

        $http.get('/api/items/').success(function(data) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                switch(data[i].category) {
                    case 1:
                        $scope.categories['Foo'].push(data[i]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $scope.categories['Eggs'].push(data[i]);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $scope.categories['Spam'].push(data[i]);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $scope.categories['Bar'].push(data[i]);
                        break;
                } 
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<div id="sidebar" ng-controller="sidebarCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in categories">
        <div class="header">{{ key }}</div>
        <ul class="spam">
            <li ng-repeat="category in val | orderBy:'short_name'"><a href="#category/{{ category.id }}/">{{ category.short_name }}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please console.log the response (both on production and development)

Comment: Can you provide the HTML that you are pushing to the menu.

Comment: @IlanFrumer I've done that, the responses are 100% identical (i've done a diff of them).

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Dieterg/Jf9TE/. If it works local and not on the server it's probably server related..

Comment: @DieterGoetelen That's what I thought, but I can see no discernible difference between server/local. I was hoping I'd made some simple error . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: On the remote server the frontend was being deployed through Django. Django's template tags and Angular template tags are both `{{ }}`. This caused a conflict. Since Django processed the HTML first, it was removing the template tags which caused Angular to render empty HTML elements.

The fix I found for this was wrapping my frontend in `{% verbatim %}` tags. This lets Django know that we do not want to process this block.

Comment: Heres an example: {% verbatim %}<h1>{{key}}</h1>{% endverbatim %}